# How to Declare VARRAY with Integer variable as Number of Elements in Oracle19c

Tags: plsql, oracle19c

Trying to declare a PL SQL VARRAY with the 'Number of Elements' as a previously declared variable but I get this error:

> PLS-00325: non-integral numeric literal NUM_ENV_COUNT is inappropriate in this context

Here is what I tried:

```
Declare 
    num_Env_Count INTEGER := 3;
    type arr_text is VARRAY(num_Env_Count) of VARCHAR2(2000);
    arr_Env_Type arr_text := ('D','V','P'); 
Begin
    for i in 1..num_Env_Count loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arr_Env_Type(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Have you tried it? If you do/did then you get a PLS-00320 indication that the expression is malformed. I understand the desire to avoid repeating the litteral variable. You can achieve the same wit a nested table.

```
Declare 
    type arr_text is table of VARCHAR2(2000) ; 
    arr_Env_Type arr_text := arr_text('D','V','P'); 
Begin
    for i in 1..arr_Env_Type.count loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arr_Env_Type(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Belayer, I was hoping to not use a table for reasons that I did not go into. But if there is not another option then i will.
And yes, I did try it. Actually I get this for an error (but i thought it was a bit excessive for the post):
`Error report -
PLS-00325: non-integral numeric literal NUM_ENV_COUNT is inappropriate in this context
PL/SQL: Item ignored
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
PL/SQL: Item ignored
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"`

Comment: With your statement "I was hoping to not use a table" you have fallen into Oracle's poor choice of terms: they use TABLE in different contexts. In this case "table of" creates a collection  almost identical to VARRAY (another type of collection) - slight different what you can do with them but very little. See [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005) for both.

Comment: @casewolf In PL/SQL, a `varray` is just a functionally crippled `nested table` collection type with a `limit` clause you don't need. I can't understand why anyone would want to use one.

Comment: so have they removed varray from oracle 19c?

Comment: No. [Varray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-E932FC04-C7AD-4562-9555-8BA05446C0B8)s are still present. The OP problem being they attempted to use a defined variable to define the array. That is wrong. The max size must be specified as a *integer literal*. As @WilliamRobertson puts it a varray is  `functionally crippled nested table`. I have used Oracle interminably since version 8i , but never seen any use for varray.

Comment: I suppose if you want a collection column in a database table (generally a bad idea, but anyway) then a varray imposes a maximum number of values, which might be a useful sanity check in some situations, and also it is stored inline as part of the table block rather than as a separate object, which might be efficient in some situations. But as a variable type in PL/SQL programs, I've never seen the point of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. And all you need is to use constants, constants can be used as the size limit of a data type, not only for varray.

And by the way, another error in your code is:

```
arr_Env_Type arr_text := ('D','V','P');
```

Which should use:

```
arr_Env_Type arr_text := arr_text('D','V','P');
```

for initializing a varray.

And here's the full example:

```
SQL> Declare
  2      num_Env_Count INTEGER := 3;
  3      type arr_text is VARRAY(num_Env_Count) of VARCHAR2(2000);
  4      arr_Env_Type arr_text := ('D','V','P');
  5  Begin
  6      for i in 1..num_Env_Count loop
  7          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arr_Env_Type(i));
  8      end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
    type arr_text is VARRAY(num_Env_Count) of VARCHAR2(2000);
                            *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 29:
PLS-00325: non-integral numeric literal NUM_ENV_COUNT is inappropriate in this
context
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated


SQL> Declare
  2      num_Env_Count CONSTANT INTEGER := 3;
  3      type arr_text is VARRAY(num_Env_Count) of VARCHAR2(2000);
  4      arr_Env_Type arr_text := ('D','V','P');
  5  Begin
  6      for i in 1..num_Env_Count loop
  7          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arr_Env_Type(i));
  8      end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
    arr_Env_Type arr_text := ('D','V','P');
                             *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 30:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated


SQL> Declare
  2      num_Env_Count CONSTANT INTEGER := 3;
  3      type arr_text is VARRAY(num_Env_Count) of VARCHAR2(2000);
  4      arr_Env_Type arr_text := arr_text('D','V','P');
  5  Begin
  6      for i in 1..num_Env_Count loop
  7          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arr_Env_Type(i));
  8      end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```